# Unable to RDP after running docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker, rdp

I am running docker on windows. But I am getting this error:

```
17:07:22  ---> Running in 8c6a46bbe049
17:07:33 container 8c6a46bbe049260df0ef60b165bd7929a2d8368dcb2baa3cffc7434175a2f811 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: winapi error #2147749890 (0x80041002) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"8c6a46bbe049260df0ef60b165bd7929a2d8368dcb2baa3cffc7434175a2f811","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"VolumePath":"\\\\?\\Volume{885e371e-7607-11e9-a9ef-00155de60a79}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\8c6a46bbe049260df0ef60b165bd7929a2d8368dcb2baa3cffc7434175a2f811","Layers":[{"ID":"70d02c58-59c2-5c57-832b-040fbae4082d","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\3f3b1333b3e56c53c9cdedab9c4ec0e536b923e35c4cfbb64d68d775f7e189ab"},{"ID":"f2b424b8-a849-53e1-9257-7e17fcf4a3fa","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\874be3b3d29cd1420a8799b482648281a5a04a4604b6f955b305f16c5ffd87db"},{"ID":"865b0b0c-60dc-5052-9af1-6f48b0081b58","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\ca13b9af8dcc734a0b7dab288ff35a9de9e0b1831122d80315038a368e4be979"},{"ID":"e027a8bd-497f-51a0-bba6-56de6579fd8c","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9b2b43be7ff215bea3764306e1d8bbc5a2663c418b5af5643cf720b3604e1909"},{"ID":"754b58d8-c4c4-526a-84df-17b6113fd181","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\47284b3fd596123a45b89439805ba7f38a7900b1bd67696fafc508f247ca8879"},{"ID":"170bb839-9260-50cf-9f16-2d104a0a41a0","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\963bfd0727440da144ef3634b9201cf122704bf6171b2306a513c8cc9ca1bd7b"},{"ID":"a3fb6aee-3e04-54c1-8e5b-e665ee073dfe","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\1daa28b5b08959c93789085549c21165ae66eaebb21092c6019d04939b544085"},{"ID":"a4b61e7f-94cc-5174-95cf-cd5840cd0a92","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\c81fd28ba0796e1447eee305a9c05f088a0b3ef7920d5fb20b44399fbe584079"},{"ID":"ac5b7f9d-6b96-56fb-93b8-276e30c421ed","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\58c0426733a33c783f6e3c359c83a63fb31c00fe629bb82764d6a1871b5ac433"},{"ID":"1cd2b979-13de-5fdd-a19b-d33d85fb14eb","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\5eae35195cd3f58f2d02312aa5df2fec6f87cedf57f41554b625ddac21dddf66"},{"ID":"bee4c6c2-fda9-53d1-97a2-730790e98655","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\54e2d38e2056906db9e434c33c546a0e536a29a545fe98406be4c1836d90887d"},{"ID":"d30d22d3-5197-555b-928c-d0f2f2099a61","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\21c171679948030094aa20ecc6c9cf02ea0cc6b438f9a0fde0eb1f76e057d825"}],"HostName":"28224361016f","MappedDirectories":[],"HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["6864626d-9cdf-4e21-9a34-2ae818f2e8f5"],"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}
17:07:33 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Unfortanely, as soon as I get this error, I am not able to RDP to the remote windows machine anymore ( it's on aws ).  So I am not able to investigate further by doing RDP.

[ FYI, my jenkins master is running docker commands on this windows container/slave via SSH ].
Any help/hint will be appreciated here.
I can still run some commands via ssh on the machine if some information needed.

Maybe the two events "not able to RDP" and "the docker error" are somehow connected. But I don't know how.

The docker machine keeps working fine. RDP also works fine in the beginning. But sometime after connecting it as a slave ( and running docker commands via ssh ), RDP stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the my problem was occuring due to some cleanup utility deleting up the system files required for mstsc ( and also required for docker ).
Everything started working fine after I switched off the cleanup utility.
Thanks for the help though.